# Iphone Developer license

Tags: xcode, licensing, iphone-developer-program

I have completed an app using an old iphone sdk. My machine is running leopard. I would like to upload it to the app store and I understand that I have to enroll as an apple developer. What is plain old stupid is that I cannot read any official documentation about uploading to the appstore without purchasing a developer's license. I don't even know if I can upload with my version of xcode and ios sdk. or if i even go through xcode to submit my app for review. my question is how do i go about submitting my app for review and is it possible to do without upgrading my machine? Regardless of the price it is extra money that I do not want to spend.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) for more.

Answer (score 3):

The developer program is free. You need to pay just in case you want to submit your application. You can register and see any documentation

Comment: I have already tried that I can see a bit more but not everything. I can't find the actual process that I need to go through to submit an app to the appstore. Does anybody have a handy link that has this the closest thing I could find was for paying members only. I need to know before I purchase the license if I can even upload with my old software. does apple require the latest sdk do they require the latest version of osx etc.